# Constructing Pandas Dataframe: Treating as columns or rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I find it hard to remember how Pandas decides to treat list as column or row at different times.

What is the general rule that is easy to remember?

Example:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[['x','y','z'],['a','b','c']])
```

x   y   z
a   b   c

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'A':['x','y','z'],'B':['a','b','c']})
```

x   a
y   b
z   c

Comment: In the first instance, your array-like structure has a shape of 2 rows and 3 columns, in the latter it's completely different case, the dict keys are the columns and the values are the row values for that column, you can see why the first behaviour occurs when you try `np.array([['x','y','z'],['a','b','c']]).shape`

Comment: @EdChum But why numpy treats them as rows, while pandas treats them as columns in default?

Comment: Did you read my comment? Your 2 examples are orthogonal to each other, in the first instance you passed an array-like structure in the second you passed a dict, how are they similar and why should they be interpreted in the same manner?

Comment: @EdChum Yes I read your comment but your comment is merely a description of the behaviour not explanation. Why are they similar you ask? First one is list of list, second is dict of list. But first one treats list as row, second treats list as column. In jezrael 's answer you can see a parameter can be set to change its interpretation of the dict. I am just asking how should I understand these different kinds of default interpretation.

Comment: @EdChum Maybe I should ask: Why the array-like structure has a shape of 2 rows and 3 columns, instead of 3 rows and 2 columns?

Comment: Arrays are declared as row, column order when it's 2-D: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html, this behaviour is adopted from numpy, with a dict the default behaviour is to treat the keys as columns, the `from_dict` method allows you to change the dict orientation but this doesn't exist for the `DataFrame` ctor

Answer (score 3):

`df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':['x','y','z'],'B':['a','b','c']})`
is best way of using pandas. This means 'A' is the column header and reference, ['x', 'y', 'z'] are values of that column.

You can even further filter rows etc. based on this like `df[df['A']=='x']` to get only those rows which have value x in column 'A'

Answer (score 0):

In second approach you can use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with parameter `orient`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={'A':['x','y','z'],'B':['a','b','c']}, orient='index')
print (a)
   0  1  2
A  x  y  z
B  a  b  c

b= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={'A':['x','y','z'],'B':['a','b','c']}, orient='columns')
print (b)
   A  B
0  x  a
1  y  b
2  z  c
```

and first perfect explain [EdChum in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763641/constructing-pandas-dataframe-treating-as-columns-or-rows/40763745#comment68751764_40763641).